# How to list all class properties without initiate a new object in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to list all of class properties by using `Mirror`.

```
Mirror(reflecting: Person(name: "a", age: 1)).children.count 
Mirror(reflecting: Person.self).children.count
```

From the code above. The first line, it returns correctly but the second one isn't working as first.

If I want to list all the class properties without initiate a new object. How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Is problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
Mirror(reflecting: Person()).children.count
```

Just change .self to (). you will get result you want.

Comment: In my question, I want to do that with out initiate a new object but for your answer `Person()` is the way for initiate a Person object isn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't initiate new object.